# How to know if the GPS signal has fixed my position on Lollipop?

Tags: gps, 5.1-lollipop

On Jellybean when the phone was trying to find my GPS location there was a flashing indicator in the status bar and a static one when the location was found.

On lollipop the indicator doesn't flash, so how do I know if the phone has a GPS fix or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this app: [GPS Status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) It will show a hollow notification icon when an app requests location, and the icon gets filled in when the GPS fix is acquired.

Comment: That's a workaround more than a solution. Somehow, GPS Status is remaining open even after I stop using the GPS enabled apps.